# CE-MAGETWO-67805.patch Installation error

Tags: magento-2.1, css, product-images, patches

I try to install CE-MAGETWO-67805.patch file for image resize issue but it is not installed it shows error[image] I also tried another method,
1. create patch file and upload it magento root folder
2. run using browser like www.mysite.com/patch.php it shows "done" text only
Also checked patch file installed or not but it is not installed.
I solve image resize issue from update may magento site 2.1.6 to 2.1.7 but some css not file js file not loading properly as per my purchased theme and css not get changed when change in css file using ftp.i guessed it is solved by installing patch file. Please somebody help me to solve my issue..

Answer (score 0):

You need to enter into the root directory of your magento. The above image shows that you are at the document root path but not Magento's root directory. Navigate to the Magento's root directory and run the same command again.

**EDIT:**

**Root Directory:** This is the directory that has been already configured in your server. Generally this path will be `/var/www/public_html`. So what ever the files that you will be placed in this folder, those will be available for the public over internet.

**Magento's Root Directory:** This is also one of the folder which is available inside the public_html directory. This is the folder which is responsible for your magento application. You might have renamed this folder as per your usage. But this is folder which has the files of magento's application.

So as the above commands are related to magento's application, you need to enter inside this folder and run those commands.

**NOTE:** These are the basic folder paths that a Magento Developer or any web developer will easily understand. Even if you didnt understand by now, it would be great that you can approach any Magento's developer as this is related to patch installation. If anything goes wrong, you can't even understand what it is.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Please explain what exactly Magento's root directory and root directory because I don't know

Comment: above answer has been edited. Check it out now.

Comment: ok, I placed the patch file inside the public_html if i enter the root directory and rerun the command may paste the patch file into the root folder?

Comment: For security purposes, you need to place the patch file inside the Magento's folder and you need to also run the command inside the Magento's folder itself. So whatever the operations/commands/functions related to Magento should run inside of the Magento's folder itself.

Comment: Did you know exactly where magento root folder placed in magento 2.1.7 because there is many magento folder placed like magento template files and module files.

Comment: And why i am any changes in magento css files it not affected and please tell me how to change the magneto logo for admin login screen also inside of admin panel

Comment: It would be helpful to you if you go through this link http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-static-view.html

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful, did you know how to change magento logo in magento login screen and for all admin pages

Answer (score 0):

I have magento 2.1.6 and also have magento purchased thebear theme after theme customization it not load exact theme css and js are not working properly and already face some issues,
1. product images resize issue
2. css and js not loading
I guessed it is version problem i have to update the current magento 2.1.6 to magento 2.1.7 the product images issues solved but css and js not working properly and I also try to install CE-MAGETWO-67805.patch file i face some errors and finally css and js not working properly and patch file not installed. Somebody there please help me..